# Control a knob on a Honeywell fan via ESP8266

Tags: microcontroller, control, wifi, esp8266, hobbyist

Hey all I am wondering what all I would need in order to control this knob on my 
[Honeywell 2-in 1 Air Circulator Fan, HT-9700](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001R1O2XW)

[image]

I am wanting to use a ESP8266 in order to control it via wifi. I know how to do it on that side but I am unsure what's available for the other side (the knob) in order to "turn" the knob or hook into the knob wires.

more images:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

OK So here it is:

BROWN wire = Low fan speed
RED wire = HIGH fan speed
BLACK wire = HOT

With the black prob on BLACK and the red prob on RED with the fan ON/HIGH I get: 09.9
With the black prob on BLACK and the red prob on BROWN with the fan ON/LOW I get: 00.0
With the black prob on BLACK and the red prob on RED with the fan OFF/OFF I get: 124.4
With the black prob on BLACK and the red prob on BROWN with the fan OFF/OFF I get: 124.4

Note I am using the AC mode on my multi meter that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You should make a schematic of that. Otherwise it is really just a guessing.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a Mains Voltage switch. So a relay (or two) of the same specs would work. Since it's two position you have to map it out with a multi-meter. Keep in mind this is Mains voltage, so Danger, beware.

Or if you want to mechanically control it, a stepper motor or solenoid or any other hacked on physical control rod of some type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Passerby. Happen to be able to set up a schematic of the Mains Voltage Switch and how it would connect?

Comment: @StealthRT without seeing that specific switch, or wiring, I can't tell.

Comment: updated my OP with more images